# How can I clone bitcoin 0.16.1 version (not the latest one ) with git command

Tags: bitcoin-core

this is the version that I want to clone :

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/releases/tag/v0.16.1

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly clone a tree you have to first take the full repository then checkout the commit you want.

For the 0.16.1 version execute these commands in a shell:

```
git clone https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin
git checkout dac5d68
```

more informations here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43411941/i-cannot-clone-git-tree

Comment: Easier: `git checkout v0.16.1`